# How can I force any links clicked within a WebView to open in Safari?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, hyperlink, webview

I have a WebView in my application and I would like any links clicked within the WebView to open in Safari (instead of the WebView itself).

I am developing the application in Swift.

What is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is done essentially the same way in Swift as in Obj-C:

First, declare that your view controller conforms to `UIWebViewDelegate`

```
class MyViewController: UIWebViewDelegate
```

Then implement [`webViewShouldStartLoadingWithRequest:navigationType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:) in your View Controller:

```
// Swift 1 & 2
func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType {
    case .LinkClicked:
        // Open links in Safari
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(request.URL)
        return false
    default:
        // Handle other navigation types...
        return true
    }
}

// Swift 3
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    switch navigationType {
    case .linkClicked:
        // Open links in Safari
        guard let url = request.url else { return true }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        } else {
            // openURL(_:) is deprecated in iOS 10+.
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
        return false
    default:
        // Handle other navigation types...
        return true
    }
}
```

Finally, set your `UIWebView`'s delegate, e.g., in `viewDidLoad` or in your Storyboard:

```
webView.delegate = self
```

Comment: Ok. The only bit I don't understand it the `class MyViewController: UIWebViewDelegate`. What do I do with this? Thanks

Comment: In Swift, you can declare that your class conforms to a protocol by adding the protocol name after the class name ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267)). In your case, it will probably look something like `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate { ...stuff in the class... }`

Comment: Thanks @RonaldMartin, It works like charm, thank you so much

Comment: How to achieve the same with WebKit?

Answer (score 8):

According to recommendations in apple docs

[image]

Also UIWebView is deprecated after 12 iOS

Here is solution using Swift 5.3 and WKWebiew

First replace your UIWebview with WKWebview

Then conform to WKNavigationDelegate and implement method

[image]

Here is code

```
extension WebViewControllerImpl: WKNavigationDelegate {
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        guard case .linkActivated = navigationAction.navigationType,
              let url = navigationAction.request.url
        else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
            return
        }
        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
   }
}
```

Then set 'navigationDelegate' for your wkWebView

```
wkWebView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Comment: if you load a local html file add this in the gurad: UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)

Comment: Thanks! If you want to open the url inside the webview use webView.load(navigationAction.request) instead of  UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)

Answer (score 7):

Updated for swift 3

```
func webView(_: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.open(shouldStartLoadWith.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to implement the method `webViewShouldStartLoadingWithRequest:navigationType` on your web view's delegate and look for the links you want to open in Safari. If you send those off to the OS with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:]` they will open in Safari.

Answer (score 1):

Updated for swift 4.2

```
func webView(_: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebView.NavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebView.NavigationType.linkClicked {
        UIApplication.shared.open(shouldStartLoadWith.url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```