# Opening hyperlink in a browser from iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to iOS development. I created a basic html page with hyperlink. I converted the html page into app using the following code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lupView: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        lupView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "lup_package/lup/index", withExtension: "html")!))


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Everything works good when I build it to iPad Air. But when I tap on the hyperlink, the target website is opening in the app itself. I would want that to be opened in a browser. Please help me to achieve that and it would be great if you explain me is that working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to open a url using Safari, the following should help.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
}
```

In case you want to open hyperlinks on your WebView using Safari. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574599/7113238) out. You need to use `webView:shouldStartLoadWith` delegate method. Remember to set `lupView.delegate = self` in your view controller or Storyboard.

```
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {

        if navigationType == .linkClicked {
            // Open links in Safari
            guard let url = request.url else { return true }

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                // openURL(_:) is deprecated in iOS 10+.
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
            return false
        }

        // Handle other navigation types...
        return true
    }
```

Comment: i have that hyperlink in html document as tap <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a> to go to google.

Comment: Edited my answer