# Nativescripts - Opening a browser on button click in a web view

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using NativeScripts angular to create a web view inside my app. When I click a button inside the web view I would like to open a webpage in the browser.

[This post shows how to do it using swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574272/how-can-i-make-any-links-within-a-webview-open-in-safari-in-xcode) and I have the ability use native libraries in my [iOS project using the marshaling technique](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/runtimes/ios/marshalling/marshalling-overview), but I am having difficulty converting to Typescript.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    if(isIOS)
    {
        let webView = UIWebView;
        let loadREquest = NSURLRequest;
        let navType = UIWebViewNavigationType.LinkClicked;
    }
}
```

My second attempt was to use the [this plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webview-interface) but I am uncertain how to listen for the click event on the click of a specific element in my web view.

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import {WebView, LoadEventData} from "ui/web-view";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import {isAndroid, isIOS} from "platform";
let webViewInterfaceModule = require('nativescript-webview-interface');
import * as utils from 'utils/utils';

export class AboutComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
@ViewChild('webview') webView: ElementRef;
private oLangWebViewInterface;

constructor(private page: Page){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setupWebViewInterface();
}

private setupWebViewInterface() {
    let webView: WebView = this.webView.nativeElement;

    this.oLangWebViewInterface = new webViewInterfaceModule.WebViewInterface(webView, 'http://myurl.net/about');

     //Is it possible to structure this to listen for the click of an element in my web view with id of #navigate
    this.oLangWebViewInterface.on('click', function(eventData){
        utils.openUrl('https://energy.gov');
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you want to open url in browser?

Comment: yes upon clicking a link that is inside a web view

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked and answered on the NativeScript forum: https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/how-to-make-links-in-a-webview-to-open-in-the-default-browser/945/2

For completeness, this is the code:

```
exports.webViewLoaded = function(args) {
  var webview = args.object;
  var TNSWebViewClient =
      android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: function(view, url) {
          if (url != null && url.startsWith("http://")) {
            console.log(url);
            // use openUrl form utils module to open the page in a browser
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }

      });
  if (isAndroid) {
    webview.android.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webview.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webview.android.setWebViewClient(new TNSWebViewClient());
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the support. but (1) this answer is in JS and was looking for TS (2) does not work on iOS

Comment: As a note on that: On Android lvl 21+ the `url` needs to be used as `console.log('---> open url ', url.getUrl().toString());` if you want to use `openUrl`

Answer (score 1):

here is Android version that works with Android 8 and 9 (tested). iOS does not, if someone has idea please leave a comment.

```
exports.webViewLoaded = function(args) {
var webview = args.object;  
if (platformModule.isAndroid) {
var TNSWebViewClient =
    android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
        shouldOverrideUrlLoading: function(view, url) {
            console.log('Show url parameters: '+url);   
            // utilityModule.openUrl(url); // for API below 24
            utilityModule.openUrl(parseInt(platformModule.device.sdkVersion) < 24 ? 
url : url.getUrl().toString()); 
            return true; 
        } 
    });
} else { 
    // else iOS
    console.log("ios webview preocessing"); 
}
if (platformModule.isAndroid) {
      console.log("for android platform");
  webview.android.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
  webview.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
  webview.android.setWebViewClient(new TNSWebViewClient());
} 
if(platformModule.isIOS){
    console.log("for ios platform");
    webview.ios.scrollView.scrollEnabled = true; 
    webview.ios.scrollView.bounces = true;
    //webview.ios.setWebViewClient(new TNSWebViewClient());
} 
}
```